# How do we convert pdf in html format in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, pdf, getcontent

Following code takes me with pdf but i wanted to view this pdf as html because in my pdf some buttons are clickable and i wanted to capture that click event from pdf so it is not possible in pdf and that's why i need that pdf converted into html.

Can anyone guide me how can i achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

```
<apex:iframe height="400px" width="800px" src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P0o00001wQYwS"></apex:iframe>
```

Comment: Is this pdf rendering Salesforce content like a VF page ?

Comment: @RedDevil, No, i am having one pdf file which needs to be render in vf page but not in pdf mode, in html mode so i can capture click event on that pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce doesn't have any built-in PDF to HTML functionality.  I would consider using an external service to convert the PDF to HTML, then save those HTMLs as Visualforce pages.  Once in VF page format, you have lots of options to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brian but can you please tell me what kind of external service i can use to convert pdf to html ?

Comment: No clue - start google searching and see what comes up.  I haven't had to do something like this before